# How do I find out how macPorts stole my port:80?

Tags: macos, macports, mamp

I had MAMP installed (and working fine) then I tried to install mongoDB through macPorts. macports then began installing a bunch of dependencies. after that, http://localhost started giving an "It Works!" screen. after rebooting to see if it might fix it, I found that I could not start my MAMP server. console said this:

```
9/13/10 1:20:54 PM  [0x0-0x12012].de.appsolute.MAMP[133]    (48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

I know that macPorts did something stupid to mess with me. how can I find out what it installed thats stealing port:80?

here's some command I've tried: (:80 didn't work, so I just used 80)

```
$ sudo netstat -an | grep 80 
Password:
tcp46      0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
udp6       0      0  fe80::21e:52ff:f.123   *.*                    
udp6       0      0  fe80::1%lo0.123        *.*
```

and:

```
$ lsof -i :80
COMMAND   PID        USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   39u  IPv4 0x0ab806b0      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49515->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   40u  IPv4 0x0ab87ec8      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49517->sstatic.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   41u  IPv4 0x0ab88aec      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49516->pz-in-f95.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   42u  IPv4 0x0ab97334      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49518->sstatic.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   47u  IPv4 0x0ab87abc      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49519->sstatic.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   48u  IPv4 0x0ab886e0      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49520->sstatic.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   50u  IPv4 0x0ab89b1c      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49521->sstatic.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   51u  IPv4 0x0ab86680      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49522->peak-colo-196-216.peak.org:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   54u  IPv4 0x0ab81ef8      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49523->gravatar.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   55u  IPv4 0x0ab82710      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49524->gravatar.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   56u  IPv4 0x0ab8a334      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49526->64.34.80.176:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-b 451 biting_duck   57u  IPv4 0x0ab812d4      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.198:49525->pv-in-f101.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: "It Works!" Is from apache (i.e. your MAMP install). It must already be running

Answer (score 17):

From what you describe about launchd errors and /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf, it sounds like the copy of Apache installed with the base OS got turned on.  Check System Preferences -> Services -> Web Service, and turn it off if needed.  If it's not turned on there, try:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

...and if *that* doesn't work, take a look in /Library/LaunchDaemons to see if something else has been installed that's launching the system copy of Apache (/usr/sbin/httpd).

Comment: You are 100% right! Something must have turned that on (I know I didn't). I feel so dumb now running around in circles only to find out it was that stupid checkbox in the System Preferences. Gordon Davisson, You Rock the kasbah!

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Davisson, "It works" was puzzling me - you saved the day!

Comment: I wonder thou, _what_ might turn on apache just like that without user interaction. Same happened to me, and this answer solved the issue (altho theres no more such setting in Mac, the terminal command did the trick). But I by god know I did not run anything to actually activate such service at all, and it just happened all of a sudden, without any particular action done prior. As well, MAMP was involved.

Answer (score 4):

On Max OS 10.1, Mountain Lion, turning off apache fixed this problem for me.

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Answer (score 2):

OS X had inbuilt apache webserver installed, which is located on /etc/apache2.
The message ""It Works!" is displayed when somehow the apache webserver is started.
Below are the process to stop/ start it.

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo apachectl start
```

sudo is needed as webserver access port 80.

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDB port](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/databases/mongodb/Portfile) doesn't install anything that would require or use port 80. Nor does any of its dependencies. Furthermore, the only way a MacPorts port could grab port 80 on startup is if it installed a launch daemon, but MacPorts doesn't activate any launch daemons on its own (you have to do that manually).

However, you can find out what program is listening on a particular port by executing

```
$ lsof -i :<port>
```

For example,

```
$ lsof -i :80
```

will show you the program listening on port 80. That should narrow down what is grabbing the port.

Comment: no dice. it just shows firefox, which I'm using to try and figure this out. :(
I appended the code to my main question because the comment doesn't support code blocks

Comment: You need to `sudo` or lsof only shows files opened by your processes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your httpd.conf files are correct. This means: No more then 1 'Listen 80'. If you have Listen 80 (or whatever port) more then once, this will trigger the binding error.

I hope this is useful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

If some service defines that it will listen to port 80, launchd will reserve it during the initial boot. It can be apache, but it can be something else as well. If you do not have apache, but have this problem try

```
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
grep -R 80 .
cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
grep -R 80 .
```

It should show you agents listening to port 80. Uninstall and restart!